# Rails skip other validations if one fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need a help with Rails ActiveRecord validations.

I have a model with some validations on different fields:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :custom_validation
  validates :field1, :field2, presence: true
  validates :field3, uniqueness: true

  def custom_validation
   # if condition
   #   errors.add(:field4, 'error message')
   # end
  end
end
```

I need skip validations on field1, field2, field3 if custom_validation fails. 
I know that I can do this just to add condition on validations of field1, field2 and field3:

```
validates: field1, field2, presence: true, if: custom_validation
```

However this solution seems to me a bit ugly and I want something more DRY. Is it possible?

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see how you would do that without overriding the built in rails validations. The crux is that the validations are declared when the class is loaded and not in the instance.

The alternative to using `if: :custom_validation` on all of your validation could perhaps be to override the `valid?` method and remove the errors for the other keys:

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  super
  if errors.key?(:field4)
    errors.keys.each {|k| errors.delete(k) unless k == :field4 }
  end
  errors.empty?
end
```

Comment: I've tried to use these snippet, but it didn't work. I got an error about unknown method except for errors.

Comment: Ah, the errors "hash" might not have `.except` which is an ActiveSupport  addon to the Hash class. Edited.